# How would look like calldata for bytes[] calldata argument?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, memory, calldata

Imagine I have a function with such signature in Solidity:

```
function doThing(bytes[] calldata arr) external;
```

how are elements of **arr** are packed in bytes? I would say that first 4 bytes is `bytes4(keccak256("doThing"))`, then 32 bytes with arguments offset for array beginning. On this offset we have length of array (32 bytes). And then again, for every **bytes** element, we have an offset, length, and elements. Am I right? It would be cool to see some